# Connecting Apple Wireless Keyboard with USB-Receiver

Tags: keyboard, usb, bluetooth

I'm using a [Aten CS533](http://www.aten.com/Mobility-&-USB/Tap--USB-to-Bluetooth-KM-Switch/Tap-(USB-to-Bluetooth-KM-Switch)-Tap-your-desktop-keyboard-into-an-iPhone%C2%AE-or-iPad%C2%AE!~CS533.html#.VVtFpGF0c_V) to pair a USB-Keyboard with my PC, a MacBook Pro and my iPhone. I'd now like to upgrade the wired keyboard to an Apple Wirless Keyboard. But I'm not sure how to pair them.

Is there any sort of „Bluetooth to USB-dongle“ that does not require the management of an OS? So that I pair the Keyboard with this Dongle or alike and that device mimics a USB-keyboard at the USB-port of my switch?

Comment: I"m not sure what you are asking. What is your goal? To connect and Apple wireless keyboard to both a MacBook Pro and an iPhone? You don't need any extra hardware if that is your goal.

Comment: Well, sort of. First of all: the wirless keyboard can only be connected to one device at a time. As I'm using a PC, a MacBook and an iPhone the changing of devices is really cumbersome. So I used this Aten device as a KVM-switch. Now the problem is connecting the wireless keyboard to the switch. I need a Bluetooth-receiver that couples with the wireless keyboard  without making this via an OS that needs a PIN etc.

Comment: The question makes it sound like you haven't bought a new keyboard yet, so why not just use the Apple Keyboard with Numeric Keypad? It's a USB keyboard that has the same key switches as the Apple Wireless and MacBook Keyboards. http://store.apple.com/us/product/MB110LL/B/apple-keyboard-with-numeric-keypad-english-usa?fnode=56

Comment: If you're looking for a really good keyboard without spending a ton of money my favorite is the CODE keyborad from WASD. I bought the full size keyboard with the green key switches and typing on it is so much better than typing on any of the Apple keyboards. https://codekeyboards.com

Comment: Actually I do have already access to a Wireless Keyboard. Thanks for the suggestion – but having no cords visible is sexy – you have to admit it.

Comment: For me, having a good keyboard with mechanical key switches trumps a more sexy desk.

Comment: Actually I really like the keys on my MacBook Pro – which are basically the same as on the wireless keyboard. Sorry.

Comment: To each their own.I learned to type on manual and IBM Selectric typewriters, so I like a a firmer feel. I type too many accidental letters on Apple's keyboards, so I have to slow down to compensate.

Comment: @Heinzelchen did you ever figure this out?